# API for Einstein Content Selection

Tags: marketing-cloud, einstein, content-builder

I want to automate pushing new assets to Einstein Content Selection. Is there a way to do that like an API?

Also I’m wondering if there is a way to mark assets that are already in SFMC Content Builder, as ECS assets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update:
Here is the API documentation for ECS asset Add and Edit, as well as MC Einstein authentication:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud-einstein/guide/mc-intro-einstein-content-selection-api.html

---

I'm the product manager for ECS. We are working on an API for ECS assets. I can't promise a release target, but it is a high priority. For now the best way to add assets in bulk is via CSV file.

We have just released an update to the UI for adding assets to allow you to select content from Content Builder. Check it out by adding a new asset from the View Assets list page. You can add an image from your desktop, Content Builder, or by URL.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently not an API to load assets into ECS, but I've heard this is on the roadmap.

You also can not flag a CB asset to be used in ECS you would have to import the URL from CB into ECS

Comment: thank you for your answer. do you know maybe if there is another  way  to automate publishing new assets into ECS (FTP?), thank you in advance